# Turn pandas column into another row record

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

A simplified form of my current pandas df is as follows:

| Team1 | Team1_Rank | Team2 | Team2_Rank | Final_Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1234 | def | 9876 | 13 - 32 |

what would be an efficient method to create a new df of the following form?

| Team | Team1_Rank | Opp | Opp_Rank | Final_Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1234 | def | 9876 | 13 - 32 |
| def | 9876 | abc | 1234 | 32 - 13 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two copies of the DataFrame where you rename the columns differently. In the second one also flip the order of 'Final Score' around the '-', then join the results. This also maintains the original Index for each row that way you can see what was grouped.

```
df1 = df.rename(columns={'Team1': 'Team', 'Team1_Rank': 'Team_Rank',
                         'Team2': 'Opp', 'Team2_Rank': 'Opp_Rank'})

df2 = df.rename(columns={'Team1': 'Opp', 'Team1_Rank': 'Opp_Rank',
                         'Team2': 'Team', 'Team2_Rank': 'Team_Rank'})
df2['Final_Score'] = df2['Final_Score'].str.split(' - ').str[::-1].str.join(' - ')

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

---

```
  Team  Team_Rank  Opp  Opp_Rank Final_Score
0  abc       1234  def      9876     13 - 32
0  def       9876  abc      1234     32 - 13
```